# Which is better with a dequeue, to use push_back()/pop_front() or push_front()/pop_back()

Tags: c++, stl

When using a std::deque as a FIFO, which pair of push/pop function is better?

- push_back(), pop_front()
- push_front(), pop_back()

I suspect there is no difference in terms of efficiency, but at least which is the most "idiomatic" (i.e. which is the one that most programmers use)?

Thanks

Comment: `When using a std::deque as a FIFO` Stop there. Why did you choose a double-ended queue if you don't actually want to use both ends?

Comment: There are some corner cases where I'll need full access to both ends, but most of the time it's going to behave as a plain FIFO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most std::queue implementations seems to use :

> push_back(), pop_front()

By the way if you can, you'd better use std::queue directly

Answer (score 4):

A deque is not a container meant to be used to implement FIFO and so there can not possibly be an idiomatic way to implement a FIFO with it. If you want a FIFO, use `std::queue`. If you insist on implementing it using deque then any of the proposed solutions is as good as the other.

Comment: @Drax I have completely edited my answer, the first version suggested a way to implement a LIFO not a FIFO

Comment: I think that first sentence might be too strongly worded: as the standard's declaration for `std::queue` is `template <class T, class Container = deque<T> > class queue;`, and its definition is little more than aliasing `push` to `push_back` and `pop` to `pop_front`, it's verging on actually wrong to say `deque` shouldn't be used to implement `queue`.

Comment: @jthill queue is an implementation of a FIFO, no matter its underlying container, a deque is a container that provides all the functionality of a queue plus additional operations. Therefor it can not be that deque is more optimal than queue for implementing a FIFO. Also you should not forget that readability and maintainability is better if you use queue for this purpose - anyone knows that a queue is a FIFO, while it is not that easy to spot a deque is used as FIFO.

Comment: If you also need indexing into the FIFO, then I'd argue that `std::deque` is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

Write a loop and time both ways

with only two choices you should be able to get your best answer for you architecture and your compiler version

It's best not to assume anything about efficiency.